# Update a textView text when an object is added to an array without overriding the previous object's textView text

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift4.2

I'm trying to update a textview whenever an object is added to an array and show that text in the textview like this:

```
"object 1"
"object 2"
```

the issue is that every time a new object is added to the array it overwrites the object before it so it will just show:

```
  "object 2"
```

Here is the code I'm using, I'm not completely sure how to append the text so it shows all items in the array once a new item is added instead of just displaying the last item added.

```
   struct ObjectData {
   let name: String
   let type: String
   let code: Int
 }

    var updatedObjectArray = [ObjectData]() { didSet {
                self.updateObjectData(object: self.updatedObjectArray)
            }


       func updateObjectData(object: [ObjectData]) {

                for objectData in object {
                      self.ObjectTextView.text = objectData.name
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loop, you are setting the text to a new value on every iteration, thus removing your last iteration's changes. You can append your names to a new string, then set the text at the end of the for-loop like this:

```
func updateObjectData(object: [ObjectData]) {
    var objectStrings = ""
    for objectData in object {
        objectStrings += objectData.name + "\n"
    }
    self.ObjectTextView.text = objectStrings
}
```

Or a swiftier way without the ending newline by mapping ObjectData to its name and joining with a newline:

```
func updateObjectData(object: [ObjectData]) {
    self.ObjectTextView.text = object.map({$0.name}).joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like that:

```
func updateObjectData(objects: [ObjectData]) {
   var text: String = ""
   for object in objects {
        text += object.name + "\n"
   }
   self.yourTextView.text = text
}
```

Comment: This creates an extra line break at the end of the string.  (might or might not be a problem for the OP)

Comment: Yeah sure, he can check for the last index, or use 'map' with 'joined' operator

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `name` property of objects in the loop. You need concat properties into the single variable instead and assign whole text.

```swift
func updateObjectData(objects: [ObjectData]) {
    let text = objects.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: "\n")
    ObjectTextView.text = text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, you're overriding the textView.text each time this loop is run:

```
for objectData in object {
    self.ObjectTextView.text = objectData.name
}
```

Easiest option might be to create a var and append to it and then set that as the text of the textview or use .map and .joined on the array of objects.

1) update the above to:

```
var string = ""
for objectData in object {
    objectStrings += objectData.name + "\n"
}
self.ObjectTextView.text = string
```

Downside to this is that you get the extra line break at the end, which can easily be cleaned up if needed.

2)  update the above to:

```
self.ObjectTextView.text = object.map{$0.name}.joined(separator: "\n")
```

This is the swifty option that first creates an array of objectNames and then joins them with the supplied separator.